# Moving an element further on click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want an element to move another 10 pixels to the right when i click on a button, how do i do that?

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
placeholder.style.left += 10;
```

My current code only locks the element to the 10th px and does not change the position when i click the button again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style.left` only understands when you add a unit of measurement at the end, in this case it should be pixels, so "px". You'll need to create another variable to keep track of the value, and add "px" afterward.

`var pos = 0;
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
pos += 10;
placeholder.style.left = pos + "px";`

Comment: Alternatively, they can retrieve the numerical distance using `parseInt(placeholder.style.left)`. It does have the "px" at the end, but parseInt is smart enough to ignore that.

Comment: @DanielKarlsson Good to hear! Don't forget to [✓] accept the answer that solved your problem so that others can also see it in the future :)